# jmeter tcpsampler - unchecked 'reuse connection' on 3.1 forces new connection?

Tags: jmeter

A very basic question hoping for a quick answer regarding JMETER 3.1:

TCPSampler, if you have 're-use connection' unchecked, does it force a new TCP connection for each thread and/or over each item in the loop?

example: Given 5 threads with a 10 loop, will it send 50 individual tcp connections, 5 connections, 10 connections, or will it try to re-use existing connections if they are available even though it is unchecked?

Thanks for any clarification -- prior searches were based on older versions (2006ish range seems to be the last time this question was heavily asked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TCPSampler, if you have 're-use connection' unchecked, does it force a
>   new TCP connection for each thread and/or over each item in the loop?

The latter. Each item.
Means, every call to sampler in every loop in every thread.
If by "loops" you meant "loop iterations count", and each loop contain only one TCP sampler - then yes, it's gonna be 50 for 5 threads.

So, basically, every call to sampler - that's the answer.

As for having this option turned on, it is more comlicated, check [this](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/Reference/TcpSampler):

> If "Re-use connection" is selected, connections are shared between
>   Samplers in the same thread, provided that the exact same host name
>   string and port are used. Different hosts/port combinations will use
>   different connections, as will different threads. If both of "Re-use
>   connection" and "Close connection" are selected, the socket will be
>   closed after running the sampler. On the next sampler, another socket
>   will be created. You may want to close a socket at the end of each
>   thread loop. If an error is detected - or "Re-use connection" is not
>   selected - the socket is closed. Another socket will be reopened on
>   the next sample.

Comment: thanks, if some other people agree or if you have a reference, that would be helpful.  The intent is that I *want* it to do the 50 individual connections, but any solid, reliable confirmation will help :-)

Comment: oh, that's easy, you can find it right in the user manual (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler): "If an error is detected - or 'Re-use connection' is not selected - the socket is closed. Another socket will be reopened on the next sample."