# Jmeter closing tcp connections

Tags: java, jmeter, netty

I have a server written in Java using Netty, and I'm testing it using Jmeter. What Jmeter is doing is every time it sends a request to the server, it sends it using a different port and different connection, not reusing the same TCP connection with the threads.

As a sample I set up a test with 5 Threads with an infinite loop, and a timer of 1 second between requests. It sends the requests, but doesn't reuse the connection and after that one second, it sends another request using a different port every time.

Is there any way to make it so Jmeter reuses connections?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you enable the 'Re-use connection' checkbox. Then, take a look at TCP Sampler Config: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler_Config

Also take a look at the following: [jmeter tcpsampler - unchecked 'reuse connection' on 3.1 forces new connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424666/jmeter-tcpsampler-unchecked-reuse-connection-on-3-1-forces-new-connection)

Connections can be reused among samplers in the **same** thread but multiple thread groups sharing the same connection I don't think is possible.

Comment: I do only have one thread group. I was previously using Http request but i tried tcp sampler with reuse checked and that still closed the connections.